# finding out which Jars are needed for a step in pentaho kettle

Tags: java, jar, classpath, pentaho, kettle

I have a Java application with an embedded pentaho-kettle executor in it. basically it's a war (usually running from within jboss or tomcat) that executes KTRs using a java.
my setup is pretty much the same as in this post [Pentaho Kettle within a web application](http://labs.consol.de/lang/en/blog/kettle/pentaho-kettle-within-a-web-application/)

basically my question is this:

**how can I tell which jar files I need in my classpath when executing a KTR?**

or

**how can I find the dependencies for a specific step?**

for example, lets say I want to use the 'User Defined Java Expression' step, well, then through trial and error I now know that I have to have 'Janino.jar' in my classpath.

But what about other steps, how can I tell which Jars they require to execute?

There must be some better way, any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

Try [Jboss Tattletale](http://www.jboss.org/tattletale), a code analysis tool that produces among other things a report with missing classes.

This is an example of how to run it in standalone mode:

java -Xmx1024m -cp  /c/dev/software/jboss-tattletale/tattletale-1.1.2.Final/javassist.jar   -jar   /c/dev/software/jboss-tattletale/tattletale-1.1.2.Final/tattletale.jar c:/temp/report

With this a report should be generated in c:/temp/report that includes among other things a page with missing classes. From there with [findjar](http://findjar.com) it's possible to find the missing jars.

Comment: is there a way to filter results in such a way as to track the dependencies starting from a single class?

Comment: This tool mentions that use case, track dependencies of a single class http://www.dependency-analyzer.org/ (never tried it tough)